# Android: Get string resource from app base locale

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

Is there a way to get the base localization for a string? So let's say you have a string id, `R.string.id`, I want the value from the `strings.xml` file, outside any localized folders.

Using `context.getString(R.string.id)` returns the string in the current locale. You can request the string in a specific locale by using `configuration.setLocale("fr")` to get the french version for example. Without knowing the base/original locale of the app, is there a way to get the string value of the app's original locale?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method for that

```
fun getBaseLacaleString(context: Context, stringId: Int): String {
    val resources = context.getResources()
    val configuration = new Configuration(resources.configuration)
    val defaultLocale = configuration.getLocales().get(0)
    LocaleList localeList = LocaleList(defaultLocale);
    configuration.setLocales(localeList);
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration).getString(stringId)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the base locale will may be unknown at the time of calling this code, so looking for something that would work for any base locale, not just "en".

Comment: @Inn0vative1 check now!